# How to retrieve the attribute name in a javascript object

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to retrieve the first attribute name in a javascript object?

Example:

```
var example = {
    'att1': { /* stuff1 */},
    'att2': { /* stuff2 */},
    'att3': { /* stuff3 */}
};
```

I'm looking for a function that returns the first attribute name, that is string: `att1`.

Comment: `Object.keys(example)[0]`

Comment: @dandavis ECMA-262 does not specify enumeration order. The de facto standard is to match insertion order.

Comment: ES6 defines key order to be insertion on alphas (and symbols) and sorted on expandos.

Answer (score 2):

Since objects are unordered, you won't be able to get the "first" one, but you can iterate over the key names and check for specific values.

```
for (var key in example) {
   if (key === 'att1') {
      var val = example[key];
   }
}
```

Comment: objects are not un-ordered. they never really were in the field, but now even the spec is clear...

Comment: unlike the `Object.keys()`-based answers, this one would hit `toString` and other prototype properties...

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, Objects are order-agnostic, so there's no *guaranteed* way to make sure that the first attribute will be what you want. There's two options for you as I see it...

**Option 1:** use an array instead

```
 var example = [
   { /* stuff1 */},
   { /* stuff2 */},
   { /* stuff3 */}
 ];
```

Now you can safely acces the first object with `example[0].

**Option 2:** use `Object.keys`

`Object.keys` will create an array out of all the *keys* (attributes, as you put it) in the object. So using your example, it would loke like this:

```
var example = {
  'att1': { /* stuff1 */},
  'att2': { /* stuff2 */},
  'att3': { /* stuff3 */}
};

// This will produce this array: ['attr1','attr2','attr3']
var keys = Object.keys(example)
```

So with `keys` now being an array of all the objects property names, ***if*** (and *if* being the focus here) you know the specific name you're looking for you can just loop over keys until you find it like so:

```
 keys.map(function(key) {
   if(key === 'attr1') {
     /* do something with example[key] */
   }
 });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the property do this

```
var example = {
 'att1': { /* stuff1 */},
 'att2': { /* stuff2 */},
 'att3': { /* stuff3 */}
};

for (var prop in example) {
  console.log("example." + prop + " = " + example[prop]);
}

// Output:
// "example.att1 = { /* stuff1 */}"
// "example.att2 = { /* stuff2 */}"
// "example.att3 = { /* stuff3 */}"
```

And you can get the first property do this

```
var example = {
  'att1': { /* stuff1 */},
  'att2': { /* stuff2 */},
  'att3': { /* stuff3 */}
};

for (var prop in example) {
  if (prop == 'att1') {
    console.log("example." + prop + " = " + example[prop]);
  }     
}

// Output:
// "example.att1 = { /* stuff1 */}"
```

As a function declaration

```
var example = {
  'att1': { /* stuff1 */},
  'att2': { /* stuff2 */},
  'att3': { /* stuff3 */}
};

function getFirstProp() {
 for (var prop in example) {
   if (prop == 'att1') {
     return "example." + prop + " = " + example[prop];
   }     
 }
}

console.log(getFirstProp());

// Output:
// "example.att1 = { /* stuff1 */}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the Keys by using **Object.keys** method.

```
Object.keys(example)[0]
```

Comment: There are no guarantees that this will be the right key.

Comment: @Harangue: when would that code not return "att1" ?

Comment: @Harangue @dandavis: The code wouldn't necessarily return "attr1" because there's no guarantee of the order. But you're right in thinking that it will only return the key name, not the property's value. For that you would do something like `example[Object.keys(example)[0]]`.

Comment: @TheQodesmith: can you demonstrate  a simple example of this re-ordering?

Comment: @dandavis See the 2nd answer (by @Alnitak) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

In short, the spec doesn't guarantee the order, but most browsers will in fact preserve it. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: @TheQodesmith: yeah, that is outmoded. never really was true in practice, and now it's false on paper too. it's very common mis-concerption though, so you should be forgiven for the mix-up...